# C++: Assign value to global class variable

Tags: c++

Consider the class `MyClass` that has **no** default constructor.

I want to write a code that looks like the following:

```
MyClass instance;

void init_system() {
    instance = MyClass(parameters, of, the, constructor);
}
```

The code I wrote above of course fails with the error **MyClass** has no C'tor that takes no arguments.

Is there any correct way to do it, or I must implement a workaround, e.g. using shared pointers?

Comment: It's unclear (to me at least), what you are trying to do. What do you want to initialize? Static member variables (AKA class variables)? Just create a static init method? Something else? Please clarify. Do you want a singleton? Or a static factory method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, either a default object of your class can sensibly exist, or it cannot.
In the latter case, you might be interested in [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (`boost::optional` before C++17) to defer the construction of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the initialization of the object into your `init_system()` function:

```
MyClass& init_system()
{
   static MyClass instance(parameters, of, the, constructor);
   return instance;
}
```

You may want to look up the singleton pattern, too, and read the extensive discussions about it ;)

And yes, another solution could be to use a `unique_ptr<>` or `shared_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of achieving this....

```
MyClass instance(parameters, of, the, constructor);
```

Would initialize MyClass with the correct parameters.

A singleton pattern

```
MyClass & MyClass::getInstance(){
   static MyClass instance( parameters, of, constructor );
   return instance;
}
```

with getInstance returned at the time of calling.

The second pattern improves control over when the object is constructed.